# Why passing a form control to a ViewModel is not working in ASP.NET Core 2.0?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0

I built a simple ASP.NET Core 2.0 application and I have a simple login view. I am using ASP.NET Core Identity which means I am using "IdentityUser" class

```
@model LoginViewModel

<h2 class="my-4 text-center text-lg-left">Before contacting us, please log in or
    <a asp-action="Register" asp-controller="Account"> register!</a></h2>

<form asp-action="Login" asp-controller="Account" method="post" role="form">
    <!-- To show form error after submission -->
    <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="UserName">User Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
        <span asp-validation-for="UserName" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
        <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Log In!</button>
</form>
```

As you can see, I created a view model called "LoginViewModel" which is going to detect the passed parameters in the submitted form

**LoginViewModel**

```
public class LoginViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "User name")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
```

When a user hits "Login" on the form, my ASP.NET tag helpers indicates that the post request is going to hit the "Login" action within the "Account" controller

**Here is my "Login" Action**

```
        private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;

        public AccountController(SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager, UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
        {
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _userManager = userManager;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Login()
        {
            return View(new LoginViewModel());
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel loginViewModel)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(loginViewModel);
            }


            var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(loginViewModel.UserName);

            if (user != null)
            {
                var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, loginViewModel.Password, false, false);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
            }

            ModelState.AddModelError("", "User name/password not found");
            return View(loginViewModel);
        }
```

The object "loginViewModel" that I am passing to the "Login" action is null, this means that it is not grabbing the form data on the time the user submits the form.

Any idea what I am missing here, pretty sure it is something stupid?

Comment: the inputs do not have names that match the members of the model.

Comment: @Nkosi I am using ASP.NET tag helpers, for example  asp-for="UserName" indicates that the form data is going to be injected into Model that maps this field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the tag helpers on the inputs!!

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="UserName">User Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username"
        asp-for="UserName" />    <!-- You're missing this -->
    <span asp-validation-for="UserName" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

### My 2 cents:

- You don't need to indicate the method="post". That's the default method. Also you might want to specify the area as well, just in case you have multiple controllers with the same name but live in different areas.

  ```
  <form asp-area="" asp-controller="account" asp-action="login">
      ....
  </form>
  ```
- When you use tag helper on labels, you don't need to put the text in between. The tag helper will generate that based on your `[Display]` annotation.

  ```
  <label asp-for="UserName"></label>
  ```
- You can use `HTML helpers` to generate the placeholder text from `[Display]` as well if you want. That way you don't need to hard code the text on the view.

  ```
  <div class="form-group">
      <label asp-for="UserName"></label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="UserName"
          placeholder="@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.UserName)" />
  </div>
  ```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Indeed, it was a stupid mistake that I already know the solution for. Also, thank you for explaining the helper tags for me

Answer (score 2):

You are generating manual html for you inputs and they do not have a `name` attribute so they do not post a value when the form is submitted.

Change your inputs to use the TagHelpers, which will generate the correct html, including the `name` attribute and the `data-val-*` attributes for client side validation

```cs
// <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
<input asp-for="UserName" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">

// <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
<input asp-for="Password" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
```